# QueryCredentialsAttributes() returning DOMAIN name in lowercase

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, active-directory, ldap

I am using `QueryCredentialsAttributes()` function to get username along with domain name in my code but function returning domain name in uppercase letters sometimes and Lowercase letters some times.
How to make it stable to return domain only in uppercase letters.

Comment: Why don't you just uppercase the domain after you get it?

Comment: It should be as same as we configured in AD server

Comment: That's not what you wrote in your question. _"How to make it stable to return domain only in uppercase letters."_. What shall it be now?

Comment: I need to get the domain name as same as we configured in AD server

Comment: Why would you want this? AFAIK domain names (even in AD) are **case-insensitive**. I don't think that what you are trying to do is possible. Yet I am curious what for you want this. Just for cosmetical reasons? If not we may figure a different solution.

Comment: In my AD all credentials are configured as case sensitive....

Comment: What Kind of AD are you using? I could not find any variant that allows case sensitivity on usernames. Only on passwords.